# Reduce PSD Computation without Time Information Loss

Tags: power-spectral-density

Every computation cycle I get a large array D that is X IQ samples long, sampled over several milliseconds. I am then taking the PSD via the scipy welch function each cycle to detect short bursts of signals.

However, the welch function is taking longer than the cycle time to compute which is causing data to be dropped. I have optimized welch slightly by setting noverlaps to zero, and reducing the FFT size, but it's still too slow.

I could reduce the size of D by halving it, then welch obviously computes faster. But then I lose the information from the second half of D, which could contain short bursts of signal information that I need.

Is there any way to reduce the data, without losing any time information (or bandwidth, so no decimation)? Frequency resolution is not too important.

For example I was thinking I could take the second half of D and add it to the first half of D (then repeat as necessary), which is some sort of integration. But what exactly am I doing to the signal if I do that in the time domain?

Comment: how large are we talking? Because: Welch isn't really a computationally intense thing, and my rough estimate is that for FFT sizes of say a couple thousand samples, you should be in the high multiple kilotransforms per second you can compute on a modern PC. So, maybe we're optimizing on the wrong end? It's a bit ironic that you reduced Welch's method to Bartlett's method by removing the overlap (which was the whole point), and then demand "no loss of data". We might need to talk about what you want to achieve with your PSD estimate first, before implementing it!

Comment: (that estimate above is for a single-threaded solution; Welch's method scales pretty well to multiple CPU cores, so I'm really not sure where the performance problem arises from, unless we're talking sampling rates >> 50 MS/s, or FFT sizes > 8192; for example, the FFTw benchmark files [here](https://www.fftw.org/speed/Ryzen-7-3.6GHz/) say a single-precision, out-of-place, forward 8192-point FFT (scof 8192) takes 15 microseconds, so you can do *a lot* of these in several milliseconds)

Comment: Basically I'm limited to a low power ARM CPU, so there is precious little computing available. I'm reducing to Bartletts method, as I don't believe scipy provides a direct function for Bartlett. 

I'm not sure if Scipy's welch function is optimized for parallel, I assume it involves an FFT at some point which scipy does do quite fast. I just don't know if there is any alternative to scipy's welch that may be faster.

Comment: All I want to achieve at the moment is a spectral display/data that will show stationary and short bursty signals from one block of data, and then I can record the active frequencies.

Comment: can you please actually put numbers to your requirements? (don't use "as … as possible", that's not a requirement we can work off) Start with the sampling rate. Then, define how short the burst are that you still want to recognize as burst. Then, what the frequency resolution is that you need.

Comment: Why don't you do the detection in the time domain instead? You can do a quick energy metric every N (where N is reasonably small) and the do an PSD only when there is sufficient energy in a frame or sub frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider just taking a log2 length windowed FFT rather than using the Welch method. The Welch method is a good approach when you want to see a smoothed spectral density applicable to noise densities in general where we would otherwise see a lot of variation (noise of the noise). For the case of detecting stationary signals that are sufficiently stronger than the the noise floor, a log2 length FFT may be preferred for its faster speed and sufficient signal fidelity with proper windowing.

Here are some Python bench marks on my machine using `scipy.signal.welch` compared to a a Kaiser windowed FFT for different block lengths of real data (note use of log2 lengths for optimum FFT speed, simply zero pad the data out to a power of 2 if the data isn't naturally that size; I included a case to show the dramatic improvement in processing time):

| Block length | welch(x) | FFT(x * win) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 65536 | 3.6 ms | 1.1 ms |
| 131072 | 7.0 ms | 3.7 ms |
| 262144 | 14.5 ms | 7.5 ms |
| 262157 (not a power of 2!) | 13.6 ms | 46 ms (yikes!) |
| 524288 | 29.7 ms | 16.2 ms |
| 8388608 | 461 ms | 325 ms |

For a potentially even faster FFT implementation, consider using [pyFFTW](https://pypi.org/project/pyFFTW/), or FFTW directly. Benchmarks of FFTW in an ARM Cortex A7, A9 and A15 are presented [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/FFTW-benchmarks-for-the-ARM-Cortex-A7-A9-and-A15-showing-best-case-multi-core-and_fig3_335165705).